# How to use Kotlin Native to emit LLVM IR (.bc or .ll) files?

Tags: kotlin-native

I wish to extract human readable IR from kotlin files but am not able to find the command that would do something analogous to the `-emit-llvm` option in clang. Given that kotlin native uses LLVM I figure it must also be possible to obtain this IR.